# Using APScheduler in clock.py on Heroku to call def send_email_reminder from main app

Tags: python, django, heroku, settings

I have an app that tracks users borrowing equipment. In the application I have an app "tool_req". In the views.py file I have a def called "send_email_reminder". I want this to run once a day to send emails to the borrower that the rental period is over. I have installed APScheduler and have a file "clock.py" to run in the background on Heroku. My Procfile looks like this:

Procfile.py
...

```
web: gunicorn trydjango.wsgi
clock: python clock.py
```

...

When I push the app using the following clock.py file I see the message every 3 minutes in my logs.

clock.py

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
sched = BlockingScheduler()
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every three minutes.')
sched.start()
```

So far so good.
However, when I put in the code to run the send_email_reminder, i.e.,:

clock.py

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from tool_req.views import send_email_reminder
sched = BlockingScheduler()
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    send_email_reminder('request')
sched.start()
```

I get this error:

**app[clock.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/app/trydjango/settings'**

I have tried a lot of things including various combinations of the following in my clock.py file, to no avail.

```
import os
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from tool_req.views import send_email_reminder
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tools.models import Tool, Literature
from pages.models import Person
from tool_req.models import RequestPost, LiteratureRequestPost
from django.conf import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'trydjango.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trydjango.settings")
from django.db import models
import django
django.setup()
from trydjango import settings
from django.conf import settings
from trydjango import trydjango_defaults
settings.configure()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: I ended up working with CodeMentor and switched to Celery.